# Obtener datos de error en una consulta en mysql con la condicion de que solo muestre los errores que cubren el 80% de los errores totales

Tags: mysql

Tengo la siguiente duda, si bien ya lo hice llevando los datos y procesandolos con php queria saber si ya desde la base puedo traer la informacion de la siguiente forma:

En base a esta consulta obtengo un listado de errores con sus respectivos impactos (total de esos errores):

```
SELECT mtg.idTemaGestion, mtg.detTemaGestion,
count(mtg.idTemaGestion) as total
from mac_gestion mg
inner join mac360_mac_gestion mmg on mg.idMacGestion = mmg.idMacGestion_FK
inner join mac360 m on m.idMac360 = mmg.idMac360_FK
inner join mac_tipogestion tg on tg.idTipoGestion = mg.idTipoGestion_FK
inner join datos_nomina dn on dn.idDatosNomina = m.idDatosNominaRecibe_FK
inner join site si on si.idSite = dn.idSite_FK
inner join mac_temagestion mtg on mtg.idTemaGestion = mg.idTemaGestion_FK
where mg.error = 'si'
and si.idSIte in (2)
and tg.idTipoGestion in (1)
group by mtg.idTemaGestion
order by total desc;
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Luego de esto lo que necesito es armar algo como un pareto donde solo me muestre los errores que cubren 80%.

- Mi total de errores es 189
- Como muestro en la imagen sacando el % de impacto y luego sumandolos me queda armado el grupo de datos que tengo que mostrar ya que esos cubren el 80% del total de errores, los demas no son necesarios ya que el impacto es poco o nulo.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Ahora, es posible devolver esa información por consulta directamente y no tener que procesar los datos después?
Con procedimientos almacenados? Se pueden declarar variables dentro de la consulta e ir validando desde ahi?
Me guian para saber que tengo q buscar para poder responder esta duda que tengo, muchas gracias.

**SOLUCION BASANDOME EN LA RESPUESTA:**

```
SELECT *, round((c.acumulado / total), 2) as pareto
from (
SELECT titulo, cantidad,
(select sum(cantidad) from errores) as total,
@acum:= @acum + cantidad as acumulado
from errores
JOIN (SELECT @acum:= 0) r
order by cantidad desc
) c
WHERE C.ACUMULADO/Total <= 0.80
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Claro que puedes, necesitas dos cosas:

- La suma total de las cantidades
- Y un acumulado para cada fila a partir de un ranking descendente

El total lo puedes manejar por medio de una subconsulta, el acumulado eventualmente también o usando un variable.

La siguiente es una prueba de concepto:

```
create table Errores (
    Titulo varchar(100), 
    Cantidad INT
)

insert into Errores (Titulo, Cantidad)
VALUES  ('Error A', 15), 
        ('Error B', 85), 
        ('Error C', 25), 
        ('Error D', 64), 
        ('Error E', 10) 

SELECT *,
    C.ACUMULADO/Total
    FROM (SELECT   t.Titulo,
                   t.Cantidad,
                   @acum:= @acum+ t.Cantidad AS ACUMULADO,
                   tot.Total   
                   FROM Errores t
                   JOIN (SELECT @acum:= 0) r
                   JOIN (SELECT SUM(Cantidad) as 'Total' FROM Errores) tot
                   ORDER BY t.Cantidad desc
          ) C
          WHERE C.ACUMULADO/Total <= 0.8
          ORDER BY Cantidad desc

drop table Errores
```

Resultado (Filtramos hasta el valor máximo menor al 80%):

```
╔═══╦═════════╦══════════╦═══════════╦═══════╦═══════════════════╗
║ # ║ Titulo  ║ Cantidad ║ ACUMULADO ║ Total ║ C.ACUMULADO/Total ║
╠═══╬═════════╬══════════╬═══════════╬═══════╬═══════════════════╣
║ 1 ║ Error B ║ 85       ║ 85        ║ 199   ║ 0,42713567839196  ║
╠═══╬═════════╬══════════╬═══════════╬═══════╬═══════════════════╣
║ 2 ║ Error D ║ 64       ║ 149       ║ 199   ║ 0,748743718592965 ║
╚═══╩═════════╩══════════╩═══════════╩═══════╩═══════════════════╝
```

En este ejemplo, la tabla `Errores` viene a representar tu consulta, tal vez te convenga ingresarla previamente en una tabla temporal ya que la vuelves a usar en una subcosulta, dependiendo de la versión de MySQL hasta podrías usar una [CTE](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-cte/).

Si lo que buscaras es llegar hasta la primer fila que supere el 80% podrías resolverlo de la siguiente forma:

```
SELECT *    
    FROM (SELECT   t.Titulo,
                   t.Cantidad,
                   (CASE WHEN @acum/tot.Total < 0.8 THEN 0 ELSE 1 END) as 'Mayor80',
                   (@acum := @acum + t.Cantidad)/tot.Total as 'Porcentaje'
                   FROM Errores t
                   JOIN (SELECT @acum := 0) r
                   JOIN (SELECT SUM(Cantidad) as 'Total' FROM Errores) tot
                   ORDER BY t.Cantidad desc
          ) C
          WHERE Mayor80 = 0
          ORDER BY Cantidad desc
```

Demo: [sql fiddle](https://rextester.com/LDFH32733)

Comment: Gracias Patricio ahi estoy analizando los datos y pasandolos a mi consulta, siguiente tu ejemplo llego al dato, tenes mi voto, pero ahi cuando tenga lo mio armado lo subo como actualizacion de la respuesta y te pongo el voto.

Comment: Lo que si tengo la siguiente duda, ejecutando el mismo script que vos la consulta me devuelve Error B, Error C y Error A con un total acomulado de 0.075 pero me tiene que devolver exactamente ese dato que mostras en la tabla, le faltan condiciones a la consulta?

Comment: No, la salida debiera ser la que muestro de hecho lo he probado con este fiddle: https://rextester.com/WMQB21371

Comment: Que raro, ahi en la pregunta edite y puse un print de lo que hago y me da otros datos a mi, usando exactamente lo mismo

Comment: Se calcula erroneamente el acumulado y eso hace que vuelvan otros valores

Comment: Es algo relacionado con el order by, ahi puse un print en la pregunta al final, si no uso order by se calcula ok si lo pongo no, en vez de recalcular el acumulado trae el que tenia al momento de no usar el order by ERROR B y ERROR D tienen (sin order by) los siguientes acumulados respectivamente 100 y 189, ya poniendo el order by tienen lo mismo cuando tendrian que tener 85 y 164 respectivamente

Comment: Creo que entendí, quieres hasta el primer caso que supera el 80%, es decir, en el ejemplo, tienes B Y D que llegan al 75%, lo que buscarías sería que también estuviera C con el cual llegas al 87%. Verifica mi última edición.

Comment: No no, esta perfecto el ejemplo que me pasas, en rextester. me devuelve el valor exacto que necesito pero cuando voy con el MISMO codigo y lo ejecuto en mysql da distinto, si ejecuto la sub consulta sin la lina que calcula el total el @acum se calcula perfecto ya cuando meto JOIN (SELECT SUM(Cantidad) as 'Total' FROM Errores) tot el  acum:= acum+ t.Cantidad AS ACUMULADO se calcula mal, ahi puse unos print en la pregunta de como se ve en mysql y que me devuelve, eso no entiendo, lo tuyo esta perfecto, no se porque en Mysql da distinto, fijate que ejecutando LO MISMO en mysql da distinto

Comment: Acabo de ver tu otra pregunta... Ahora sí.. es raro claro, dejame investigarlo

Comment: Listo el problema era el total , lo meti como sub consulta y ya funciona: (select sum(cantidad) from errores) as total, porque? No lo se, pero gracias igua me guie con tu respuesta.